# Migrating group in farm

Tags: migration, groups, server-farm

I need to replace some groups with new ones. Therefore I stumbled upon the script, which everyone references in the web.

Basically when I run

```
$farm.MigrateGroup()
```

I get a Error

> NullReferenceException. The $farm is not null and the groups
>   do exist.

Do I need to do something special like dettaching the database or stopping the farm?

Comment: pls share more of your code what you are trying to execute?

Comment: (get-spfarm).MigrateGroup("groupa", "groupb") ..

Answer (score 0):

This method $farm.MigrateGroup() accepts two parameters like source(string), target(string). without this getting Null Reference exception is obvious. See the method definition:

```
$farm.MigrateGroup(source,target)
```

visit [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.migrategroup.aspx)

Comment: Yeeh.. That's pretty obvious once you read the documentation.. That's not the question I was asking. Sure I execute the method with groups in it.

Comment: Thats why I asked you to provide complete code, what you were trying